# If $J\backslash I_i$ is a finite union of disjoint half-open rectangles then so is $\cap_{i=1}^k J\backslash I_i$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $\mathscr{T}$ be the semi-ring of half-open rectangles in $\mathbb{R}^d$, i.e. rectangles of the form $[a_1,b_1)\times \cdots \times [a_d,b_d)$. Let $I_i\in \mathscr{T}$ and $J:=J_R:=[-R,R)^d \in \mathscr{T}$. If $K=\cap_i I_i^c$ then 
$$J\cap K=\cap_i I_i^c \cap J=\cap_k \cap_{i=1}^k J\backslash I_i$$ and each set $J\backslash I_i$ is a finite union of disjoint sets from $\mathscr{T}$(since $\mathscr{T}$ is a semiring).

In this case, why is $\cap_{i=1}^k J\backslash I_i$ a finite union of sets from $\mathscr{T}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ll see what I do in my answer provided you’ll imagine the respective actions in $\Bbb R^2$.

Since $\bigcap_{i=1}^k J\backslash I_i=J\setminus\bigcup_{i=1}^k I_i=
((J\setminus I_1)\setminus I_2)\dots )\setminus I_n,$
it suffices to show that $I\setminus I’$ is a finite union of disjoint sets from $\mathscr{T}$ for each $I$ and $I’$ from $\mathscr{T}$.

Let $I=\prod_{k=1}^d [a_k,b_k)$ and $I’=\prod_{k=1}^d [a’_k,b’_k)$. For each $k$ put 
$a’’_k=\max\{a_k,a’_k\}$, $b’’_k=\min\{b_k,b’_k\}$, and $I’’=\prod_{k=1}^d [a’_k,b’_k)$. By construction, $I\setminus I’= I\setminus I’'$ and $I’’\subset I$. The set 
$I$ can be partitioned into $3^d$ mutually disjoint (maybe empty) half-open rectangles of the form
$\prod_{k=1}^d [c_k,c_{k+1})$ where for each $k$ $c_k$ and $c_{k+1}$ are consecutive members of the sequence $(a_k,a’’_k,b’’_k, b_k)$. One of these half-open rectangles is $I’’$.

Comment: Actually, this is a fact that I do know already(it's proof is given in the text where I got my question from). What I do not know is when we have $((J\setminus I_1)\setminus I_2)\dots )\setminus I_n$, and each $I\backslash I'$ is a finite union of disjoint sets from $\mathscr{T}$, why is $((J\setminus I_1)\setminus I_2)\dots )\setminus I_n$ also a finite union of sets from $\mathscr{T}$?

Comment: @takecare This is an easy induction. At each step $k$ we have a set $J_k=((J\setminus I_1)\setminus I_2)\dots )\setminus I_k$ is a union of finitely many disjoint rectangles from $\mathscr{T}$. When we remove from $J_k$ a rectangle $I_{k+1}$  it is the same that we remove $I_{k+1}$ from each a rectangle $I$ of the union, and $I\setminus I_{k+1}$ is again a union of finitely many disjoint rectangles from $\mathscr{T}$.